# Wordpress ordering posts by meta_value_date not working as expected

Tags: wordpress

When trying to output posts ordered by a date value given as post meta, the output is not as expected, and I cannot figure out why.

```
$tourDates = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'     => 'tour',
    'numberposts'   => 4,
    'meta_key'      => '_sm_tour_date',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_date',
    'meta_type'     => 'DATE',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'       => '_sm_tour_date',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => date('Y-m-d')
        )
    )
));
```

The dates for each post are being stored as YYYY-MM-DD, and this is confirmed when I add an output of each event date on the front end (Which is showing how it is outputting in the wrong order).

[image]

Can't actually think of anything to change though, and the docs I've gone over seem to suggest my code is correct (as is the meta_query).

I have no custom ordering plugins to change the ordering rules also.

Does anyone have any tips or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but try changing 'orderby' value to 'meta_value' rather than using  'meta_value_date'.

If that doesn't work, I typically have a hard time with get_posts queries that use meta_query. Did you using WP_Query instead of get_posts?

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually managed to resolve it before you answered, but I will mark yours as the correct answer because you're in the right place. By changing it from `meta_value_date` to `meta_value_num` is what made this work correctly (although I'm still unsure why the original value didn't work as expected).